# App Development for Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, appexchange, app-development

I've been looking for a way to create a salesforce marketing cloud application for my customers, but I can't find a straight answer on how to get started. Are there different development orgs for regular salesforce app development and marketing cloud app development?

Answer (score 2):

Morning Allen!
You are right, Marketing Cloud and Force.com (Sales, Service, Community Cloud) are different pieces of software running on different infrastructure (at least at the moment)
Unlike force.com there is no development or sandbox instance (at least in the traditional sense), only limited full instances.
If your customer has a Marketing Cloud instance, then request access from them (potentially to a development/testing) business unit.
If they do not, you could always register with Salesforce as an ISV for Marketing Cloud which would also get you can instance
Hope that helps!